# How to run two react native android applications on two different servers at same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have my two react native android apps which I want to run at the same time on my device.

Right now, both my applications connect to 8081 - and whenever one connects, it kicks the other one off.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command for this

```
react-native start --port 9988
```

For the official documentation, you can try the https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting#using-a-port-other-than-8081

Comment: ok thanks for answer, but how can I run my another application? Actually there is no problem with my 8081 port. I just want to run two applications. Hoe can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Expo**
By scanning the QR code with two devices you can run in two separate devices...

Comment: ok thanks for answer, Is there any another way? so, I can do this on same device by creating two node.js servers.

Comment: did you try changing the port?

Answer (score -1):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start -p 3001"
  },
```